# System.Text.Json not found even though it is part of the project

Tags: c#, winforms, restsharp, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

I have a Winforms project and I have the latest `NET6` (currently 6.0.4) version installed.

I'm using `RestSharp` and when I created the `RestClient` I get the following exception:

> File or Assembly "System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" not found.

The RestSharp nuget package dependencies show:

[image]

In `App.config` I also having the following bindings:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Json" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.4" newVersion="6.0.0.4" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I also tried using `Newtonsoft.Json` instead as explained [here](https://restsharp.dev/serialization.html#newtonsoftjson-aka-json-net), but I get the same exception above.

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Is the project built with .NET 6? Do you mean the instantiation of a `RestClient` with "created the RestClient"?

Comment: Also, RestClient is kind of obsolete in .Net 6, isn't it. Do you happen to have upgraded the project to .Net 6 from an older version?

Comment: The project is NET4.8 but I added NET6 to it.

Comment: Did you figure out any solution for this problem?

Comment: I ended up using Flurl instead of RestSharp.